# Integrating an exponential of x to the s-th degree

Tags: integration, products

So I need to calculate the following integral (which I know would somehow involve a Gamma function, except I'm not sure how):

$$
\idotsint \prod d^3 p_i \exp(-\beta A \vert p_i \vert^s)
$$

where s > 0, and each $p_i$ is independent of the others, and i runs from 0 to N.

(to those interested, this comes from trying to calculate the partition function of some general hamiltonian using the canonical ensemble (statistical mechanics))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $i$-integral can be independently evaluated:
$$
\mbox{as}\ {4\left(A\beta\right)^{-3/s}\,\pi\,\Gamma\left(3/s\right)
\over s}.
$$
$$
\mbox{So, the final result must be}\
\bbox[15px, border:1px solid navy]{\color{#44f}{\left[{4\left(A\beta\right)^{-3/s}\,\pi\,\Gamma\left(3/s\right)
\over s}\right]^{N}}}
$$